# Compiling a file type cmake.sometext with GNU make version 4.1

Tags: makefile, cmake, gnu-make

as the title says i have some problem compiling a file named `cmake.simple_bmad_program` with the command `make`.

If I am in the directory of the file and try to compile it by just using make I receive an error code: `make: No targets specified and no makefile found. Stop.` After telling make to compile this specific file by: `make -f cmake.simple_bmad_program` I receive a message: `cmake.simple_bmad_program:1: missing seperator. Stop`

I just worked myself through different questions and answers in stack overflow which recommend to replace the spaces with tabs. After I did this and the other way round the same error code occurs. Does anyone have an idea to solve this problem?

I am using the make version 'GNU Make 4.1' together with the compiler GNU 7.4.0 at the moment on ubuntu 18.04.1 system.

Maybe this is useful for you. My colleges at work could compile this file easily by using 'mk'. This command is not in my binaries folder.

The code of the file is like this (if it helps):

```
set(EXENAME simple_bmad_program)
set (SRC_FILES
  simple_bmad_program.f90
)

set (LINK_LIBS
  bmad
  xsif
  xrlf03
  xrl
  sim_utils
  recipes_f-90_LEPP
  forest
  fgsl
  gsl
  gslcblas
  lapack95
  lapack
  blas
)
```

Comment: The code in the file is [CMake language](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/manual/cmake-language.7.html), not `make`. So running `make` with this file will certainly cause issues. You should run `cmake` instead. However, this doesn't look like a complete CMake file, are there other CMake files available? Or more to this file you aren't showing?

Comment: See the description of the file from here https://wiki.classe.cornell.edu/ACC/ACL/BuildSystemOld . It is part of the ACC build system and not be meant to build separately.

Comment: squarekittles and vre this is the complete file I have. In the directory there are more files like CMakeLists.txt, README, lat.bmad, layout.bmad and simple_bmad_program.f90. However the README tells you to just use mk and it will compile which is not working.

Comment: Can you post a link to the project or name it, that we can have a closer look onto it? Otherwise it's only wild guessing.

Comment: I am just using the release bmad_dist_2019_1008 which i downloaded from https://www.classe.cornell.edu/~cesrulib/downloads/tarballs/.  I set the everything up as described in https://wiki.classe.cornell.edu/ACC/ACL/OffsiteDoc#DistDownload. Now i start my shell and go from the main directory of the unpacked download to /examples/simple_bmad_program

Comment: Do you need further information? Or do i have to specify it?

Comment: If you run `mk` and it doesn't work, or isn't installed on your system, then it would seem something went wrong during the setup. From the docs: "*For building on computers outside the Lab: Setup instructions are included in the INSTALL file included in the Bmad Distribution download.*"

Comment: running 'mk' results in the error code 'mk: command not found'

Comment: Ok, thank you really much for your help so far. I will check this on monday and will let you know if the error was a wrong setup. Have a nice weekend. ;)

Comment: Short update. I checked the environment and everything seems to be correct. After deleting the release bmad_dist_2019_1008 and downloaded the release bmad_dist_2019_1001 I got a step further. If i am executing the 'mk' now, the error code changes to: '-bash: bmad_dist_2019_1001/util/mk : No such file or directory'. Nevertheless there is a file called mk in this directory called mk. Any ideas what the problem is?

Comment: In the mk file it is written: "export THIS_SCRIPT='mk' " next line "mk-mkd ${@}" in the util directory there is a file called mk-mkd as well.

Answer (score 0):

The file is not a GNU Makefile. It looks like a cmake file, so you first need to call cmake on the toplevel directory (Where thee file CMakeList.txt is located). This will produce Makefiles for GNU Make.

Comment: I just tried 'cmake CMakeLists.txt' audit results in having a minor error code as it could not find a file in '../build_system/Master.cmake' relatively to the directory of the CMakeLists.txt and the cmake.simple_bmad_program. One directory and one file occurred right after this message which where CMakeCache.txt and CMakefiles/. I now got the problem that i don't no how i can come any further in compiling it.